# hive command error Expression Not In Group By Key product_id

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a HDFS table A written in the following format

```
user  product
U1       101
U1       102
U1       103
U2       101
U2       104
U3       102
```

...............

```
describe A;
>> user   string
   product int
```

Now if I want to aggregate users so that products by the same user are grouped together, how should I write the hive command?

```
select user, product from A group by user;

error: line 1:14 Expression Not In Group By Key product
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collect_set(col)` function in hive for aggregating products by user name.

Use below command :

```
select user,collect_set(product) from A group by user;
```

You will get output like below :

```
U1      [102,103,101]
U2      [101,104]
U3      [102]
```

Please refer [Hive Documentation for collect_set()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF))
for more information.

Comment: I assume it should be select user, collect_set(product) from A group by user? It throws out error message "line 1:26 Expression Not In Group By Key product"

Comment: Have you loaded the data into tables properly?

Comment: it seems fine. Is your function supported for all versions hive?

Comment: I tried it on hive 0.12.0. Need to check on others.

Comment: confirmed. @cast_A_Way's solution is correct for relatively new version hive