# Aggregation and grouping in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

My table structure:

```
Date      Year    Month    Code    Name
```

It will be great if I can get results as below..

```
Year  Month  Code   CodeCount  Name  NameCount
```

The structure is such that a 'Code' can have multiple 'Name' but a 'Name' will always have a single 'Code'

If this is not possible I'm fine with breaking it down to two queries

```
Year  Month  Code   CodeCount
```

and

```
Year  Month  Name  NameCount
```

I'm just staring with hive and would sincerely appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: When you group by a column then you can't select other columns along with the aggregated column.

Comment: Check out the below hive query to aggregate and return the other columns values in a list           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955050/hive-command-error-expression-not-in-group-by-key-product-id

Answer (score 0):

```
select Year,Month,Code,Name,count(*) as NameCount from table group by Year,Month,Code,Name;
```

With this I should be able to do `Select Code, Sum(NameCount)` to get the CodeCount